Capacitor in series with a button
I'm working on making my old Lift Master / Craftsman / Chamberlain garage door opener 'smart'. The original control panel uses two wires at 22 volts to control 3 functions - door toggle, light toggle, and 'vacation' toggle. Door toggle is done by simply shorting the two wires together, while the other two buttons do the same, but through a 1uF and 22uF capacitors connected in series with the buttons. What do these capacitors do in terms of the signal and how would you go about emulating such a signal (if at all) with a micro-controller like ESP32?
Intuitively, the capacitor seems seems to turn an instantaneous 'binary' off->on event into a gradual event, where the capacitance controls the time it takes to go from the complete 'off' to the complete 'on'. Is that correct and how would I go about estimating this time?
EDIT: I looked at the signal using oscilloscope. It looks like there is a base signal and the capacitors are used to chop this signal.



I think it is to give an "impulse", becuase initially the capacitor would behave like a short-circuit and then after a while like an open-circuit. So it's like to avoid you keep pressing it. However I should look to where the two ends are connected to confirm this.

@ocirocir So, in other words, this would look like a very short (timed) press?

use three reed relays

@jsotola - do you mean the opener side has three Reed relays, each with a different activation time and the capacitors were chosen to trigger either one, two or all three relays at once?

no ... you connect a relay across each switch on the control board ... or build a new control board that connects in parallel to the one in the picture

If you want to emulate it, the simplest way is to replace or parallel the existing buttons with relays.
Relays simulate the buttons while providing electrical isolation.
Your ESP can simply control any of the three relays on and off to simulate a button press.

That would be indeed the most straightforward way to do it. The obstacle is that I'm using an existing smart controller (ratgdo) that already works with the two-wire interface of the opener. I can modify the firmware, but can not modify the hardware of the controller, so emulating the press in the firmware would be the 'cleanest' solution. Still, I am exploring to see if I can hijack one of the free pins on the controller to add a third wire with the capacitor or use a pin to control a relay with the wire.
